# ScrollView with a SurfaceView

Tags: android, xml, uiscrollview

Currently I have a custom SurfaceView for a specific size of Panels that I used for my project. But I'm looking into expanding it hence I need a ScrollView to scroll it accordingly. But I'm not sure how do I merge the 2 together.

[image: Custom SurfaceView]

My SurfaceView is using a .java file to create its layout. It is not using .xml to create the layout.

```
//MySurfaceView.class

    public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback , Runnable{
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private boolean isDestroyed = false;
        private Canvas canvas;
        private Paint paint;
        private int maxWidth;
        private int maxHeight;
        private Resources resources;
        int offset;

        final byte ON=1;
        final byte OFF=0;


        int[] ledPositionControl = new int[97];
        int ledBmpSize;
        int positionControlSize;
        int maxControl=96;
        int sizeControl=0;

        int row;
        int col;

        public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            resources = context.getResources();
            init();     //load pictures 
            surfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            paint =new Paint();
        }
```

This is the class that runs the SurfaceView.

```
//Class that runs the SurfaceView Layout
public class drawingMode extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public static int screenWidth;
    public static int screenHeight;
    private SharedPreferences sPrefs;
    final byte ON = 1;
    final byte OFF = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MySurfaceView(this));

        DisplayMetrics metric = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metric);
        screenWidth = metric.widthPixels; 
        screenHeight = metric.heightPixels;
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Now how do I merge this `SurfaceView` into a `ScrollView` Layout? I have a `.xml` file that has a `ScrollView` inside but I tried to put the SurfaceView via tag wise through `.xml` but it didn't worked. I also tried the `.addView` and it didn't work too gave me some errors.

```
//I put this in a the onCreate of a class.
    myScrollView = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
            myScrollView.addView(new MySurfaceView(this));
            setContentView(R.layout.scrollsurfaceview);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you didn't specify LayoutParams. Secondly, you had  a wrong setContentView. The best way is to place ScrollView in layout.xml. If you rather prefer to do in in the code, here is a hint:

```
 ScrollView myScrollView = new ScrollView(this);
 myScrollView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));

 MySurfaceView myView = new MySurfaceView(this);
 myView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, myHeight)); 

 myScrollView.addView(myView);
 setContentView(myScrollView);     // !!!!!!
```

Comment: I'll give this a try thank you. Which do library do I import for LayoutParams?

Comment: Nevermind, the layout params worked. Its just that on  `myView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, myHeight)); ` Not sure what u meant by myHeight. Do I need to get the surfaceView size or?